# Forward traffic from vlan to tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing

I am using Mikrotik router at home. I am running one OpenVPN, one IPSec IKEv2, and 2 wireguard tunnels. However, the encryption performance on Mikrotik (CCR1009) is subpar so I decided to add a raspberry pi to the mix. What I would like to do is to create 3 different vlans for RPi, one for each tunnel and forward traffic between them on RPi. However I've failed  to do that so far. I have vlans and wg set up, added accept rules to the iptables and nat masquerade, added route but it still does not work.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.15.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.15.1.255

eth0.10: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.15.10.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.15.10.255

eth0.11: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.15.11.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.15.11.255

eth0.12: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.15.12.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.15.12.255

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.8.175.136  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.175.136
```

**IPTABLES:**

```
iptables -L -v
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0.10 wg0     anywhere             anywhere

iptables -t nat -L -v
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    wg0     10.15.0.0/16         anywhere

iptables -t mangle -L -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4   688 MARK       all  --  eth0.10 any     anywhere            !10.15.0.0/16         MARK set 0xfc
```

**ip rule**

```
from all fwmark 0xfc lookup vlan10
```

**ip route**

```
default dev wg0 table vlan10 scope link
```

My idea was that I'd set a routing mark for traffic coming from vlans with destination address !10.x.x.x and then add a routing entry for that mark, but my execution didn't go as planned ... Any help appreciated.

Comment: *added accept rules to the iptables and nat masquerade, added route* can you show them - also, I take it you've shown the RPi setup and you have set up VLAN on the router?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes vlans are configured on the router correctly. I've added ip tables/rule/route listing